# Doctrine 2 generates empty id on flush

Tags: doctrine-orm, flush, persist, string

First question on stackoverflow, little bit nervous.

So, here's the situation :
I'm using Doctrine 2 for a website. I installed it properly without pear, using the good libs and good paths in my application. I created my DB before starting to code, so I created mapping (xml & yml, just in case) with reverse-engineering method (doctrine exporter). Generated mappings are fine, then I wrote the entities files myself (the console didn't worked).

```
/** @Entity */
class Member {

/** @Id @Column(type="string", nullable=false) */
private $login;
/** @Column(type="string", nullable=false) */
private $password;
/** @Column(type="string") */
private $mail;
/** */
private $dateregister;
/** */
private $datelastconnexion;
/** @Column(type="string") */
private $description;
/** */
private $birthday;
/** @Column(type="string") */
private $website;
/** @Column(type="boolean") */
private $activated;
/** @Column(type="integer") */
private $idstatus;
/** @Column(type="integer") */
private $idcountry;
/** @Column(type="integer") */
private $idlang;

/** @Column(type="integer") */
private $idarticle;
/** @Column(type="integer") */
private $idfilters;

public function __construct($login) {
    $this->login = $login;
    $this->activated = false;
}


public function getLogin() {return $this->login;}
public function getPassword() {return $this->password;}
public function getMail() {return $this->mail;}
public function getDateregister() {return $this->dateregister->format('Y/m/d');}
public function getDatelastconnexion() {if ($this->datelastconnexion == null) return 'Never logged';
    else return $this->datelastconnexion->format('Y/m/d H:i');}
public function getDescription() {return $this->description;}
public function getBirthday() {return $this->birthday->format('Y/m/d');}
public function getWebsite() {return $this->website;}
public function getActivated() {return $this->activated;}
public function getStatus() {return $this->idstatus;}
public function getCountry() {return $this->idcountry;}
public function getLang() {return $this->idlang;}
public function getArticles() {return $this->idarticle->toArray();}
public function getFilters() {return $this->idfilters->toArray();}

public function setLogin($newLogin) {$this->login = $newLogin;}
public function setPassword($newPassword) {$this->password = sha1($newPassword);}
public function setMail($newMail) {$this->mail = $newMail;}
public function setDateregister($newDate) {$this->dateregister = $newDate;}
public function setDatelastconnexion($newDate) {$this->datelastconnexion = $newDate;}
public function setDescription($newDescription) {$this->description = $newDescription;}
public function setBirthday($newDate) {$this->birthday = $newDate;}
public function setWebsite($newWebsite) {$this->website = $newWebsite;}
public function setActivated($activate) {$this->activated = $activate;}
public function setStatus($newStatus) {$this->idstatus = $newStatus;}
public function setCountry($newCountry) {$this->idcountry = $newCountry;}
public function setLang($newLang) {$this->idlang = $newLang;}
public function setArticles($newArticles) {$this->idarticle = $newArticles;}
public function setFilters($newFilters) {$this->idfilters = $newFilters;}

}
```

Now I was trying to insert something into the database, but I'm blocked with a small problem :
When a member tries to register, he fills some informations (logins, password, etc). I make every tests to see if informations are corrects and if they are, I create a new Object Member, which I fill with every given information and automatically generated one, then I call persist() on the object, then flush().

```
$newMember = new Member($login);
$newMember -> setPassword($passwd);
$newMember -> setMail($mail);
$newMember -> setDateregister($currentDate);
$newMember -> setDescription($description);
$newMember -> setBirthday($newBirthday);
$newMember -> setStatus($status[0]); // existing object
$newMember -> setCountry($country[0]); // existing object
$newMember -> setLang($lang[0]); // existing object
$doctrineManager->persist($newMember);
$doctrineManager->flush($newMember);
```

I got some surprise looking into the database, seeing the filled ID is equal to '' (empty string), and not $login.
So... that's my question : how is that possible ? Is it because I didn't fill every property of Member before flushing ? or didn't give information on relations between entities (one-to-many, many-to-many, many-to-one) ? or anything else ? I'm on this problem for one week now, I couldn't figure it out.

For information :

- $status, $lang, $country are foreign keys.
- $article and $filters are many-to-many relations.

Thanks for reading, and (I hope) thanks for explaining me my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You must use flush like this:

```
$doctrineManager->flush();
```

after that you can access id with:

```
$newmember->getId();
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't change anything. The id is still empty (int 0 with a `var_dump($newMember->getLogin());`). I think the problem is based on the persist, not the flush, because when Doctrine adds the line in my DB, the login is empty.

Comment: Please change your identity comment like this(you must change column name etc):      /** * @ var integer $id * @ Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false) * @ Id *@ GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY") */
    private $id;

Comment: I did what you told me to and begged someone to generate the entities for me, it's working fine now ! Thank you much to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is $idarticles and $idfilters were ManyToMany relations, which I didn't specified. On construction of the object, it could be possible Doctrine 2 was not able to construct the object according to the mapping.

So the construct function looks like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->idfilters = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->idarticle = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->activated = false;
}
```

And each ManyToMany have to get their ArrayCollections in order to work.